# power Automate Dynamic Expression Evaluation

Tags: arrays, dynamic, power-automate

I am using power automate and need filter arrays to evaluate an expression. The expression needs to be generated dynamically and passed to the filter array function. For example:- Say I need to filter out records whose name is "Anand" and belongs to "Automation" department. To achieve this, I am able to hardcore the logic in filter array condition as below

@and(equals(item()?['Name'], 'Anand'),equals(item()?['Department'], 'Automation'))

This works fine in case of hard coding but I need to pass an expression for this and get this evaluated at runtime, because the conditions will be varied based on user inputs so I can't hard code this.

I tried to use a compose to store the input as

and(equals(item()?['Name'], 'Anand'),equals(item()?['Department'], 'Automation'))

and in the filter array condition, I pass something like

@outputs('Compose_4')

This has generated the below error :

The execution of template action 'Filter_array_2' failed: The result 'and(equals(item()?['Name'], 'Anand'),equals(item()?['Department'], 'Automation'))' of the evaluation of 'query' action 'where' expression '@outputs('Compose_4')' is not a valid boolean value.

Note : 'Filter_array_2' is the name of the filter array created.

Any help regarding this would be really wonderful as I am stuck on this situation right now.

I tried to use a compose to store in the expression as a string and tried to get that evaluated in the filter array condition which is not working

Comment: The `@and(equals(item()?['Name'], 'Anand'),equals(item()?['Department'], 'Automation'))` part you used before is already an expression. So, I am not really sure why you want to replace that by the outputs of a Compose action? And that won't work because a Filter array expects you define criteria/filter for items in your array and not just provide a simple true or false output boolean value. What do you want to replace/make dynamic in that first expression you used? The Anand/Automation values by any chance?

Comment: Yes, the name and department values will be dynamic, so I cannot hard code that. This is just an example for illustration. Moreover, there can be other filter criteria as well : say Name : "raj" and Age : "40". So, these criteria are pretty dynamic, so I was trying to figure out a solution to accommodate this

Comment: You can make that expression in the Filter array dynamic. Below would be a way of using two string variables `@and(equals(item()?['Name'], variables('StringVariableA')),equals(item()?['Department'], variables('StringVariableB')))`

Comment: @SaikatDasgupta has Expiscornovus solved/answered your question?